# Function that generates a sequence by from the sequence

Tags: .net, f#

How to defined a function that generates a sequence by from the sequence passed as the third argument
by taking the number of values passed as the first arguments and applying the the function passed as a second argument to them.

`dependingOnPastValues : int  -> (int list -> int) -> seq<int> -> seq<int>`

The missing past values at the start of the sequence can be considered to be 0.

`let dependingOnPastValues  (count:int) (fn : int list -> int) (input:seq<int>) : seq<int> =  failwith "pseudoRandom not yet implemented!"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
let dependingOnPastValues numValues mapper seqInput =
    seqInput
    |> Seq.take numValues
    |> mapper
```

or maybe this:

```
let dependingOnPastValues numValues mapper seqInput =
    seqInput
    |> Seq.take numValues
    |> Seq.map (fun x -> mapper numValues x)
```

or perhaps more like this:

```
let aMapper numValues x =
    x // TODO: do something with x

let dependingOnPastValues numValues mapper seqInput =
    seqInput
    |> Seq.mapi (fun i x -> 
        if i > numValues then
            mapper numValues x
        else 0
        )

let result =
    seq [1;1;2]
    |> dependingOnPastValues 1 aMapper
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, but :


let dependingOnPastValues  (count:int) (func : int list -> int) (input:seq<int>) : seq<int> =
            input
            |> Seq.take count
            |> Seq.map (fun x -> func count x)


return 

This value is not a function and cannot be applied.

Comment: And let dependingOnPastValues  (count:int) (func : int list -> int) (input:seq<int>) : seq<int> =
            input
            |> Seq.take count
            |> func
return    ->    Expecting a
    'seq<int> -> seq<int>'    
but given a
    'int list -> int'    
The type 'seq<int>' does not match the type 'int list'

Comment: I added a third possible solution. Consider not mixing sequences and lists, if possible. Choose the most appropriate data structure and stick with that if you can. Also, if you're adding a lot of type annotations to the function definitions, that might be making things more difficult for you. Many F# developers add type annotations only when necessary to resolve compile errors.